# Index Error problem when trying to shear an image

Tags: python, pycharm, index-error, shearsort

I have a university project that requires me to make a program that shears an image without using cv2 library functions. I am using pycharm and my personal fix is two for loops that go through each pixel and shears them with a factor of Bx and By. I have two problems with this code:

1. I can only set the Bx factor to a value less than 1 (otherwise I get index 602 (my img width) out of bounds error).
2. The program will only run if I set the x's range in the for loop to be the height (instead of the width), otherwise I will get an index 401 out of bounds error, which is my height.

I have tried switching them around and implementing if statements to break if the values get out of bound, but I have not found anything to work.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('IPMP.jpg', 1)

height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
print(height, width)
out = np.ones((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

def shearing(img, Bx, By):
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(height):
            img[int(x * By + y), int(x + y * Bx)] = img[x, y]

shearing(img, -0.5, 0)

cv2.imshow('shearedImage', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destryAllWindows()
```

I am open to other suggestions to solve the problem, not married to this specific approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use if statements to `continue` if values get out of bounds. If this doesn't work, show the code you tried in the question.

Comment: Firstly I've not dived too deep into this object, but I think this algorithm is not the shearing one. Secondly when you set x (for you the width) you will set the height because python matrices's indexing looks like as (rows,columns). And yes the indices try to run out of bounds because of the essence of the algorithm, but you can it handle with conditions.

Comment: When you double checked and confirm that your algorithm conform with the shear algorithm I will gladly help you further.

Comment: I tried to implement the continue function into for loops, and it still gives me index height out of bounds. The for loop looks like this after:
    for y in range(height):

        if y >= height:

            continue

        for x in range(width):
            if x >= width:
                continue
            img[int(x * By + y), int(x + y * Bx)] = img[x, y]
Ok I can't make it code form, but i inserted if statemts after each for loop function.
I am sure the shearing math is correct, it goes x' = x + y * Bx and y' = x * By + y